# Regex in Swift4 to validate fullname

Tags: ios, swift, regex, swift4, nsregularexpression

I'm looking for a regular expression to use in Swift to validate the full name. I'm looking for a regex that has a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 100 characters - Accept Accents, dashes (-) and apostrophes (') and no other special character - Upper and lower case letters and no numbers. - It must not start with a blank space and cannot have more than 1 blank space between the names.

I was using this - `"(?mi)^[A-Za-zÀ-ú](?!(?:.*\.\/\ ){2})(?!(?:.* ){10})(?!.*\.[a-z])[A-Za-zÀ-ú. '-]{5,99}[A-Za-zÀ-ú]$"` but is accepting more than one space and some names that I shouldn't

link https://regex101.com/r/493eLF/12

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try `let regex = #"^(?=.{2,100}$)\p{L}+(?:(?:\.\h|[\h'’-])\p{L}+)*[.'’]?$"#`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/H1rDaC/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a repeating group that starts with a single space followed by repeating 1+ times the listed characters in the character class.

To verify the string length, you could use a positive lookahead at the start of the string.

If there should be no trailing spaces allowed, you can omit the  `*` at the end right before the `$`

If the single uppercase chars are also allowed, you can change the quantifier for the first`[A-Za-zÀ-ú.'-]+` to `*`

```
^(?=.{2,100}$)[A-Za-zÀ-ú][A-Za-zÀ-ú.'-]+(?: [A-Za-zÀ-ú.'-]+)* *$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ql29of/1)